# Unable to compile using Picocli

Tags: java, picocli

I'm a dev student
I would love to use Picocli in my project, unfortunately I doesn't understand how to compile using Picocli
I trie to follow the instruction given here  https://picocli.info/ or here  https://picocli.info/quick-guide.html but the step to compile aren't detailed. I'm not using Gradle nor Maven but they aren't really listed as required.

This is how it tried to compile the Checksum example given in the picocli.info webpage :

```
jar cf checksum.jar Checksum.java ; jar cf picocli-4.6.1.jar CommandLine.java && echo "hello" >  hello
```

Then I simply copy paste this gived command :  https://picocli.info/#_running_the_application

```
java -cp "picocli-4.6.1.jar:checksum.jar" CheckSum --algorithm SHA-1 hello
```

And get the following result :

```
Error: Could not find or load main class CheckSum
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CheckSum
```

I tried to compile everything myself and then add the .jar like this :

```
java CheckSum -jar picocli-4.6.1.jar
```

But then the error output looks like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: picocli/CommandLine
at CheckSum.main(Checksum.java:33)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: picocli.CommandLine
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 1 more
```

Witch I don't understand since I added the dependency.

What am I missing ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm thinking that you should be giving the fully qualified name for `CheckSum`, like `com.foo.bar.CheckSum`. - are you specifying a package that CheckSum is in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the command `jar cf checksum.jar Checksum.java` only creates a jar file (jar files are very similar to zip files) that contains the `Checksum.java` *source file*.

What you want to do instead is *compile* the source code first. After that, we can put the resulting `Checksum.class` file (note the `.class` extension instead of the `.java` extension) in the checksum.jar. The Java SDK includes the `javac` tool that can be used to compile the source code. Detailed steps follow below.

First, open a terminal window and navigate to a directory that contains both the  `Checksum.java` source file and the `picocli-4.6.1.jar` library.

Now, the command to compile (on Windows) is:

```
javac -cp .;picocli-4.6.1.jar Checksum.java
```

Linux uses `:` as path separator instead of `;`, so on Linux, the command to compile is:

```
javac -cp .:picocli-4.6.1.jar Checksum.java
```

> The `-cp` option allows you to specify the classpath, which should contain the directories and jar/zip files containing any other class files that your project uses/depends on. Since `Checksum.java` uses the picocli classes, we put the picocli jar in the classpath. Also add the current directory `.` to the classpath when the current directory contains any classes. I just add `.` habitually now.

Now, if you list the files in the current directory, you should see that a file `Checksum.class` has been created in this directory.

Our `Checksum` class has a `main` method, so we can now run the program with the `java` tool:

On Windows:

```
java -cp .;picocli-4.6.1.jar Checksum
```

On Linux:

```
java -cp .:picocli-4.6.1.jar Checksum
```

> Note that when *running* the program with `java` you specify the class name `Checksum`, not the file name `Checksum.class`.

You can pass arguments to the `Checksum` program by passing them on the command line immediately following the class name:

```
java -cp .:picocli-4.6.1.jar Checksum --algorithm=SHA-1 /path/to/hello
```

When your project grows, you may want to keep the source code and the compiled class files in separate directories. The `javac` compile utility has a `-d` option where you can specify the destination for the compiled class files. For example:

```
javac -cp picocli-4.6.1.jar:otherlib.jar -d /destination/path /path/to/source/*.java
```

This should generate `.class` files for the specified source files in the specified destination directory (`/destination/path` in the example above).

When you have many class files, you may want to bundle them in a single jar file. You can use the `jar` command for that. I often use the options `-v` (verbose) `-c` (create) `-f` (jar file name) when creating a jar for the compiled class files. For example:

```
jar -cvf MyJar.jar /destination/path/*.class /destination/path2/*.class
```

Enjoy!

Comment: Wow thanks you so much ! You product looks really good so I was really frustrated to not be able to use it. And thank for the information about .jar files aswell, really helpful ! :)

Comment: No worries! Enjoy!

Comment: If you are using maven to add picocli as a dependency then you should use a plugin like maven-assembly-plugin which will allow you to automatically add all the dependencies to the jar file.